# Azure hosted applications with Active Directory single tenant authentication end up with a loop of sign in and sign out prompts

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have several .NET Core applications hosted in Azure that all use Azure Active Directory single tenant authentication.  For some reason when I post a new version of any of these applications to Azure and try to access it the following happens...

1. I'm prompted to use my currently signed in account, or use another account.
2. Once I've selected an account I'm immediately prompted to **sign out** of that account.
3. When I sign out it's recommended I close the browser and reopen before attempting to login again, so I do that.
4. Now when I open a new browser and try to access the application this entire process repeats and I'm never able to access the application.

I've had some success closing the browser and then killing any instances of it within Task Manager but not always.  Can anyone tell me a definitive way to deal with this situation?  I basically just need a way for my end users to get around this that aren't IT folks.

Comment: Nope. Its busted until ms fixes it.

Comment: @Kisaragi - Thx, that's what I was afraid of.

Comment: Opening a new browser doesn't always reset any leftover session information in cache. Private browsing doesn't help either? Would you maybe need to restart the entire app service as well? Although it is something that is maybe unwanted, i don't read if you tested it

Comment: @Marco - I've tried restarting the app service but that doesn't work.  Using an incognito tab does work sometimes BUT I can't tell my end users that's their only option for accessing the application.

Comment: please check your redirecrt URI is not set as logoutUri. Check this dicussion as well may it help you : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/544011/bypass-the-azure-ad-sso-choose-an-account-prompt-w.html

Comment: @RahulKumarShaw-MT - I've confirmed my redirect uri is set correctly and not as the logout uri.